ERROR : spark-shell \Spark\bin\..' was unexpected at this time
I`m using on Windows(10) machine. I want to install Apache Spark in my machine.
Official download page here.
Article I followed to complete the Apache Spark installation here.
What I did : 
Installed/added java, spark and hadoop and added to the path as well.


Created required system variables which are : SPARK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME



NOTE : I dont have bin in the provide value of the SPARK_HOME.

After doing all the required steps. 
The command I used is spark-shell.
Getting the following error :

While solving aforementioned error, I tired this article also, though nothing got changed : https://mytechnologythought.blogspot.com/2018/08/spark-shell-java-was-unexpected-at-this.html
Please can anyone from the community tell me how to fix it !!

later I digged more about it & let me share what worked for me.
The article I was using to install Apache Spark is click me.
While working on finding the solution, I came across this article.
I did the mentioned steps, though it didnt work.
Later, just for the trial. 
What I did is I moved all the required folder in directly to C: rather having them in some sub-director(whose names are having whitespaces in them, like: Program Files).

Later update all the System variables with the right paths.



Then I restarted the laptop.

VOILA, it worked !!!!!! 

